# Very wide columns in stacking column graph

Tags: highcharts

if one of these graphs contains more than one value on XAxis (for example "data":[[52,1], [100,1]]), the more distance between them, the greater becomes the columns. How to get rid from this problem?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UMpBL/)

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'value'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
        },    
        legend: {
        },
        tooltip: {
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                 stacking: 'normal',          
            }
        },
        series: [{"name":"RunContractid = 316 name","stack":109,"data":[[52,1], [100,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 314 name","stack":109,"data":[[49,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 472 name","stack":109,"data":[[49,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 327 name","stack":109,"data":[[49,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 476 name","stack":109,"data":[[52,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 299 name","stack":109,"data":[[52,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 298 name","stack":109,"data":[[52,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 469 name","stack":109,"data":[[56,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 479 name","stack":109,"data":[[56,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 500 name","stack":109,"data":[[59,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 320 name","stack":109,"data":[[59,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 600 name","stack":109,"data":[[59,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 326 name","stack":109,"data":[[59,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 642 name","stack":109,"data":[[59,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 312 name","stack":109,"data":[[64,1]],"type":"column"},{"name":"RunContractid = 480 name","stack":109,"data":[[48,1]],"type":"column"}]
    });
});
```

---

Found the solution - add zeros at blank points.

Answer (score 0):

You can set pointWidth parameter

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointWidth

EDIT:
[PointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange) solves problem http://jsfiddle.net/UMpBL/4/

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointRange:1,
            stacking: 'normal',
        }
    },
```

Comment: The number of columns may be different, so you cannot set some overall width.

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with it? because width can be set on serie or on all series

Comment: in most cases, the width is automatically set correctly. But for this case the width is calculated incorrectly. I think this is a bug, because if I remove the excess point and the graph becomes normal http://jsfiddle.net/UMpBL/3/